# Strange behaviour from scipy.stats.multivariate_normal

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy, probability

I fit a 3 component bivariate Gaussian Mixture Model using scikit-learn and obtained the following means/covariances

Component 1

```
Mean=[  2.01878147e+03   1.09863146e-01]
Cov=[[  6.56549549e+06   7.10777431e+01]
 [  7.10777431e+01   1.90427621e-02]]
```

Component 2

```
Mean=[  1.47870577e+04   4.01269332e-01]
Cov=[[  1.36599131e+08   1.64730583e+02]
 [  1.64730583e+02   7.26703249e-02]]
```

Component 3

```
Mean=[  1.53665912e+04   7.92136639e-02]
Cov=[[  1.76201570e+08   1.90912937e+02]
 [  1.90912937e+02   9.44458941e-03]]
```

However when I plot each component it looks like this (I rescaled two of the pdfs slightly to make comparison of the shapes easier):

[image: Gaussian PDFs]

the plot is created along these lines

```
C1 = mixweights[0]*multivariate_normal.pdf(pos,mixmeans[0], mixvars[0])
ax.plot_surface(x, y, C1, cmap=cm.gray, shade='True', rstride=1, cstride=1,alpha=0.5)
```

However for the 3rd component we can see that the density appears completely wrong, in fact the density values are being replicated in each row along the axis with the small values, almost as if it had infinite variance along that axis as opposed to the ~0.009 variance we can see in the covariance matrix. I checked that the covariance matrix is invertible so I don't know what could be causing the multivariate_norm.pdf to be returning such wrong values. Any ideas?

Comment: After normalising the data this does not happen. Given that the covariance matrix had a large determinant and is invertible I don't know what causes the strange behaviour from multivariate_normal.pdf.

Comment: Where does `multivariate_normal.pdf` come from?

Comment: Looks like a bug (in the pdf function or maybe the plotting function). A couple of ideas. (1) Try plotting just the third component. (2) Make a contour plot instead of a mesh plot. (I generally prefer contour plots anyway, since it is hard to locate points on a mesh plot.) (3) Generate a table of values of the pdf function to verify that it is being computed correctly. Probably (3) is the first thing to try.

Comment: @AhmedFasih it's a part of the scipy library, a fairly recent addition.

Comment: @RobertDodier I did all of these things to make sure it wasn't me who was wrong. As I said above once I normalised the data (ie 0 mean 1 std dev) then this doesn't happen. My initial reaction was that the covariance matrix for the unnormalised data was problematic but I don't see that it is given it's not near-singular. The nature of the bug seems very strange, it seems to be replicating the marginal distribution for one value across an entire dimension...